# How do I write a pre/post traffic hook function in go?

Tags: go, aws-sam

I started using AWS SAM and for now I only have some unit tests, but I want to try to run integration tests in a pre traffic hook function.

Unfortunately there seems to be no code example for Golang, all I could find was for Javascript.

From [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#appspec-hooks-lambda) example I pieced together that I have to use the code deploy SDK and call [PutLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatus](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/codedeploy/#CodeDeploy.PutLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatus), but the specifics remain unclear. The [aws code example repo for go](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/go/example_code) has no examples for code deploy either.

More Information about the topic that I am looking for is available here https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/safe_lambda_deployments.rst#pretraffic-posttraffic-hooks.

I want to start out by testing a lambda function that simply queries DynamoDB.

Comment: go code to query DynamoDB from lambda serverless : is that what you want ?

Comment: no, I have working go code for that. This is what I am looking for: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/safe_lambda_deployments.rst#pretraffic-posttraffic-hooks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this works:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "encoding/json"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/codedeploy"
)

type CodeDeployEvent struct {
    DeploymentId                  string `json:"deploymentId"`
    LifecycleEventHookExecutionId string `json:"lifecycleEventHookExecutionId"`
}

func HandleRequest(ctx context.Context, event CodeDeployEvent) (string, error) {

    // add some tests here and change status flag as needed . . .

    client := codedeploy.New(session.New())
    params := &codedeploy.PutLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatusInput{
        DeploymentId:                  &event.DeploymentId,
        LifecycleEventHookExecutionId: &event.LifecycleEventHookExecutionId,
        Status:                        "Succeeded",
    }

    req, _ := client.PutLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatusRequest(params)

    _ = req.Send()
}
```

Comment: thanks, I guess if my tests fail I change the Status to something like failed and that will cancel the cancary deployment and trigger the rollback?

Comment: That's correct. I tested by returning `Status: "Failed"` and it rolls back as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The last points that's not quite clear to me is: How do I actually call the lambda in a pre traffic hook? If it was a post traffic hook and the lambda was behind APIGateway I could simply call the API via http, but how do I test the lambda before it can receive traffic and how can I pass data into it?

Comment: As a pre traffic hook it can only be invoked by Sam (there is no way to simulate the deployments locally AFAIK) - you just declare it in the SAM template and update your cloudformation stack via SAM deploy. SAM then will handle the invoking of the function and supply a deployment ID and the code needs to just call back into CodeDeploy (Note that the hooks only trigger on the second SAM deploy though). 
You could call the function locally with [lambda invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/invoke.html) if you really want but I am not sure how useful that would be.

Comment: For running the actual tests locally you could just use a separate binary. So do something like put the test logic in its own package and include that in the above function for sam deploys and use another function/ binary for local. Alternatively you could modify the above to not do the SAM/ codedeploy parts when run locally.

Answer (score 0):

I got around to implement this and want to share my complete solution.

After figuring out how to use it, I decided against using it, because there are a couple of drawbacks.

- there is no way to expose a new version of the canary to a dedicated portion of the user base, that means sometimes they'll hit the new or the old version
- invoking functions that publish to sns will trigger all downstream actions, which might get the new or the old version of the downstream services, which would cause a lot of problems in case of breaking APIs
- IAM changes affect both version immediately, possibly breaking the old version.

Instead, I deploy everything to a pre prod account, run my integration and e2e tests and if they succeed I'll deploy to prod

the cdk code to create a canary deployment:

```js
const versionAlias = new lambda.Alias(this, 'Alias', {
    aliasName: "alias",
    version: this.lambda.currentVersion,
})

const preHook = new lambda.Function(this, 'LambdaPreHook', {
    description: "pre hook",
    code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('dist/upload/convert-pre-hook'),
    handler: 'main',
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.GO_1_X,
    memorySize: 128,
    timeout: cdk.Duration.minutes(1),
    environment: {
        FUNCTION_NAME: this.lambda.currentVersion.functionName,
    },
    reservedConcurrentExecutions: 5,
    logRetention: RetentionDays.ONE_WEEK,
})
// this.lambda.grantInvoke(preHook) // this doesn't work, I need to grant invoke to all functions :s
preHook.addToRolePolicy(new iam.PolicyStatement({
    actions: [
        "lambda:InvokeFunction",
    ],
    resources: ["*"],
    effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
}))

const application = new codedeploy.LambdaApplication(this, 'CodeDeployApplication')
new codedeploy.LambdaDeploymentGroup(this, 'CanaryDeployment', {
    application: application,
    alias: versionAlias,
    deploymentConfig: codedeploy.LambdaDeploymentConfig.ALL_AT_ONCE,
    preHook: preHook,
    autoRollback: {
        failedDeployment: true,
        stoppedDeployment: true,
        deploymentInAlarm: false,
    },
    ignorePollAlarmsFailure: false,
    // alarms:
    // autoRollback: codedeploy.A
    // postHook:
})
```

My go code of the pre hook function. `PutLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatus` tells code deploy if the pre hook succeeded or not. Unfortunately in case you fail the deployment message, the message you get in the cdk deploy output is utterly useless, so you need to check the pre/post hook logs.

In order to actually run the integration test I simply invoke the lambda and check if an error occurred.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/base64"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/codedeploy"
    lambdaService "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/lambda"
)

var svc *codedeploy.CodeDeploy
var lambdaSvc *lambdaService.Lambda

type codeDeployEvent struct {
    DeploymentId                  string `json:"deploymentId"`
    LifecycleEventHookExecutionId string `json:"lifecycleEventHookExecutionId"`
}

func handler(e codeDeployEvent) error {
    params := &codedeploy.PutLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatusInput{
        DeploymentId:                  &e.DeploymentId,
        LifecycleEventHookExecutionId: &e.LifecycleEventHookExecutionId,
    }
    err := handle()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        params.Status = aws.String(codedeploy.LifecycleEventStatusFailed)
    } else {
        params.Status = aws.String(codedeploy.LifecycleEventStatusSucceeded)
    }

    _, err = svc.PutLifecycleEventHookExecutionStatus(params)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed putting the lifecycle event hook execution status. the status was %s", *params.Status)
    }

    return nil
}

func handle() error {
    functionName := os.Getenv("FUNCTION_NAME")
    if functionName == "" {
        return fmt.Errorf("FUNCTION_NAME not set")
    }
    log.Printf("function name: %s", functionName)

    // invoke lambda via sdk
    input := &lambdaService.InvokeInput{
        FunctionName:   &functionName,
        Payload:        nil,
        LogType:        aws.String(lambdaService.LogTypeTail),                   // returns the log in the response
        InvocationType: aws.String(lambdaService.InvocationTypeRequestResponse), // synchronous - default
    }
    err := input.Validate()
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("validating the input failed: %v", err)
    }

    resp, err := lambdaSvc.Invoke(input)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to invoke lambda: %v", err)
    }

    decodeString, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(*resp.LogResult)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to decode the log: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("log result: %s", decodeString)

    if resp.FunctionError != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("lambda was invoked but returned error: %s", *resp.FunctionError)
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    sess, err := session.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    svc = codedeploy.New(sess)
    lambdaSvc = lambdaService.New(sess)
    lambda.Start(handler)
}
```